# Change status text in columns.yaml in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

[image]

I Want to Change Yes/No to Active/Closed for that i have tried

```
status:
        label: Status
        type: group
        conditions: status in (:filtered)
        options:
            pending: Pending
            active: Active
            closed: Closed
```

AND

```
status:
        label: Status
        type: switch
```

The above code is found in https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-switch

Can anyone have any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no yaml configuration for `switch` column type to do this, but two other solutions are possible

### Method 1. You need to override localization file.

- Create `lang/en/backend` directory in your project folder
- Create file `lang.php` and add there:

> ```
>  <?php    
>    return [
>        'list' => [
>           'column_switch_true' => 'Active',
>           'column_switch_false' => 'Closed'
>        ],     
>    ];
> ```

- (optional) The base lang file is `modules/backend/lang/en/lang.php` if you have to override another messages

**Downside**:

- It will affect ALL `switch` type columns

### Method 2. Create partial for this column

- Change yaml configuration for the column to:

  status:
      label: Status
      type: partial
      path: column_status
- Add file `_column_status.htm` to the according folder in `controllers` folder with content:

> ```
> <?php if($value) :?>
>     Active
> <?php else: ?>
>     Closed
> <?php  endif ?>
> ```

Comment: I have tired it second method. And it works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in your model:

```
public function getIsActiveAttribute()
    if ($this->status) {
        return 'Active';
    } else {
        return 'Closed';
    }
}
```

in modelname/columns.yaml

```
isActive:
    label: Status
    type: html
```

you can return html string from function getIsActiveAttribute()

eg.

```
public function getIsActiveAttribute()
    if ($this->status) {
        return '<i style="color:green">Active</i>';
    } else {
        return '<i style="color:red">Closed</i>';
    }
}
```

Comment: there is not a "html" type in new version of OctoberCMS but you can define list function in Plugin.php file:   public function registerListColumnTypes()
    {
        return [
            'html' => function($value) { return $value; }
        ];
    }